# passing variable from blade(view) to route or controller

Tags: php, view, laravel-4, controller, laravel-blade

I want to pass the selected item's $id to my controller for doing changing on it .

it's my index.blade.php (view)code

```
<table>
 @foreach($posts as $p)
<tr>
 <td>{{$p->title}}</td>
 <td>{{substr($p->body,0,120).'[...]'}}</td>

  <td>{{HTML::link('posts_show',' Preview',array($p->id))}}</td>
 <td>{{HTML::link('posts_edit','Edit',array($p->id))}}</td>
 <td>
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE','url'=>array('posts.delete',$p->id)))}}
 {{Form::submit('Delete')}}
 {{Form::close()}}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

but it doesnt pass $id to my controller's methods.

thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to show us your route and controller files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to set route parameter. Your route should be like that.

```
 Route::get('post','postController@index');
 Route::get('posts_create',  function (){  return View::make('admin.newPost'); });
 Route::get('posts_show/{id}','postController@show');
 Route::get('posts_edit/{id}','postController@edit');
 Route::post('posts_delete/{id}','postController@destroy');
```

If you want to use named route `{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('posts.edit', $p->id))) }}`, you need to set name like that.

```
 Route::post('posts_edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'postController@edit', 
'as' => 'posts.edit'));
```

You can check [routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) in [laravel official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/).

**Edit**

For now, your form in view look like that.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('posts.edit', $post->id), 'method' => 'POST')) }}
```

In route,

```
Route::post('posts_edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'postController@edit', 
'as' => 'posts.edit'));
```

In PostController,

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // do something
}
```

I hope it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your good explanation about "route" property . but my main problem exists again

Comment: You mean you can't access `$id` in your controller yet.

Comment: I use your second solution ('Form....route..') for all of them . instead of using mine {{HTML ....}}. and it works now :). I really dont know what is my problem with that . but it's working with this and it's enough to me . thanks alot man

Comment: Thank you for this, it helps me in my problem which passing a parameter from view to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your route has a name `posts.destroy`, if that is the case you should use `route` instead of `url` as a parameter

`{{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE','route'=>array('posts.destroy',$p->id)))}}`

Comment: I did it but gave me this error:`Route [posts.destroy]` (or anything else) `not defined. (View: \myBlog\app\views\posts\index.blade.php)` .I dont know why but whenever I used `route` or `link_to_route` I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

it's my route:

```
 Route::get('post','postController@index');
 Route::get('posts_create',  function (){  return View::make('admin.newPost'); });
 Route::get('posts_show','postController@show');
 Route::get('posts_edit','postController@edit');
 Route::post('posts_delete','postController@destroy');
```

it's my postController:

```
class postController extends BaseController{

public function show($id){
    $post=Post::find($id);
    $date=$post->persian_date;
    return View::make('posts.show')->with('post',$post)->with('date',$date);
}

public function edit($id){

    $post=Post::find($id);
    if(is_null($post)){
        return Redirect::route('posts.index');
    }
return View::make('posts.edit')->with('post',$post);
}

public function update($id){
    $input=array_except(Input::all(),'_method');
    Post::find($id)->update($input);
    return Redirect::route('posts.index');

}

public function destroy($id)
{
    Post::find($id)->delete();
    return Redirect::route('posts.index');
}
```